# how to change color of particular word in textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is user input in textarea like "somefoo foo". I want to change foo word color to blue.Code below doesnt work!

```
<body>
<div><textarea rows="4" cols="50">somefoo foo</textarea></div>
<script>
var regx=new RegExp("foo");
var value=' otherfoo';
$("textarea").html( $("textarea").val().replace(regx,value.fontcolor('blue')));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: interesting...thanks!!! i will try to implement this and see how it works.

Comment: one more question: is it possible to create a link for a particular word inside textarea by implementing similar logic.What do you think?

Comment: Yes. You could modify one of the answers to wrap the word in an anchor rather than a span

Comment: hi @Sexy Turnip...i tried to implement the answer that you suggested but they are all about highlighting not for giving color to text and this needs different approach i think, i managed to do that though using  my own way.But there is a bug, i needed to make textarea 'color':'transparent' in order to show the text behind it, and when i do so, cursor disappears and how can i show cursor?is there a way to do that?